# Angular 6 Build throws error Property xxx does not exist on type xxx

Tags: angular, typescript, formgroups

I have a weird problem whereby my project builds and runs 100% but when I try getting it to build on SYS server I get the:

```
ERROR in (html) Property 'ExampleDate' does not exist on type 'ExampleComponent'.
```

(I have replaced the names of the properties, types and so on). If I remove this from my html/ts the project builds fine and all the other form parts are ok.
Somehow the build agent has a problem with this particular one. Please note I have been working on this project for ages and been doing several check ins/builds every day, without any issues. Can you spot anything weird?

.html

```
 <form [formGroup]="myForm" class="my-form" novalidate>
    <div class="inline">
        <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput disabled [(value)]="someValue" [matDatepicker]="ExampleDate"
                     placeholder="Example Date" formControlName="ExampleDate">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

.ts

```
 buildExampleForm() {
        this.myForm = this.form.group({
            ExampleDate: ['', ''],
            SomeOtherExampleDate: ['', ''],
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an extract of `MatDatePicker` usage from [Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples#datepicker-locale)

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Different locale</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Add the line `<mat-datepicker #matDatepicker></mat-datepicker>` in your html

Something like below

```html
 <form [formGroup]="myForm" class="my-form" novalidate>
    <div class="inline">
        <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput disabled [(value)]="someValue" [matDatepicker]="ExampleDate"
                     placeholder="Example Date" formControlName="ExampleDate">
              <mat-datepicker #ExampleDate></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just browsed through countless posts and I noticed some people mentioned that the PRD build is strict in a way it doesn't like template types that are not declared in code behind... so the simple: `ExampleDate: any;` fixed the problem.